# How can i take screenshot of URL or URL to PNG on Share Hosting server using PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, shared-hosting, snapshot

I am getting an issue taking screenshot of the URL using PHP

I tried **ImageMagick** with the following code.
But no idea how can i use it.

```
import -window root images/my1.png
```

I replaced root with "my url"

I run above command using **exec** in PHP, but it not give me any output.

Can anyone give me any suggestion on this.

I would be very thankfull to you for this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *take screenshot of URL*?

Comment: Hi @Alan Machado, I want to create jpg or png of URL

Comment: You may use `curl` along with [`imagecreate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) functions then.

Comment: @AlanMachado, i used CURL for retrieving content or HTML . But no idea how can i use CURL for PNG or JPG.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `webkit2png` or similar like this:

```
webkit2png http:/google.com -o grab
```

which will give you these files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     14754 30 Sep 18:46 grab-thumb.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     68830 30 Sep 18:46 grab-full.png
-rw-r--r--   1 mark  staff     13552 30 Sep 18:46 grab-clipped.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mark, But its a command line tool. Not for PHP. This is made for python

Comment: @SunnyPatial Tried another method. Check it out. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ImageMagick now. The other way for taking a screenshot using PHP without any additional server resource is by using Google's [PageSpeed Insights API](https://go.praveen.science/?redirect=https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/getting-started), which doesn't need any authentication of any kind. It's free and open right now, so make use of it.

Implementation details for the same are here: [**Generating Screenshots of URLs using Google's secret magic API**](https://blog.praveen.science/generating-screenshots-of-urls-using-googles-secret-magic-api/).

**Source Code**

```
<?php
  // Creating a proxy to use GET request to hit the Google Page Speed API and receive a screenshot.
  // Check if the URL parameter for our proxy is set.
  if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    // Make sure the given value is a URL.
    if (filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
      // Hit the Google PageSpeed Insights API.
      // Catch: Your server needs to allow file_get_contents() to make this run. Or you need to use cURL.
      $googlePagespeedResponse = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&url={$_GET['url']}");

      // Convert the JSON response into an array.
      $googlePagespeedObject = json_decode($googlePagespeedResponse, true);

      // Grab the Screenshot data.
      $screenshot = $googlePagespeedObject['screenshot']['data'];
      // Replace Google's anamolies.
      $screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'), array('/','+'), $screenshot);

      // Build the Data URI scheme and spit out an <img /> Tag.
      echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,{$screenshot}\" alt=\"Screenshot\" />";
    } else {
      // If not a valid URL.
      echo "Given URL is not valid.";
    }
  } else {
    // URL not set.
    echo "You need to specify the URL.";
  }
?>
```

You can also do it using Client Side:

```js
$(function () {
  // Get the URL.
  var url = "https://praveen.science/";
  // Prepare the URL.
  url = encodeURIComponent(url);
  // Hit the Google Page Speed API.
  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&strategy=mobile&url=" + url, function (data) {
    // Get the screenshot data.
    var screenshot = data.screenshot;
    // Convert the Google's Data to Data URI scheme.
    var imageData = screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, "/").replace(/-/g, "+");
    // Build the Data URI.
    var dataURI = "data:" + screenshot.mime_type + ";base64," + imageData;
    // Set the image's source.
    $("img").attr("src", dataURI);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hard Coded Screenshot of my Website:</h1>
<img src="//placehold.it/300x50?text=Loading+Screenshot..." alt="Screenshot" />
```